# How to assign rows from massive dataframe to a "container" and when container is "full", assign to a new container?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a massive dataframe with over 300,000 rows. Here is a simplified version of the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'Value':[56,13,25,7,18,91,32]})
```

I need to "place" each row into a "container" (another dataframe or some other object) until the container is "full" (i.e. the sum of the values exceeds a certain value), and then have all of the remaining rows be in a separate dataframe. The issue is due to the size of the dataframe, a row-by-row approach is not possible. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Something with `.cumsum()` might work, but in order to understand what you need, it would help to know what you've already tried based on your own research, to make a [mcve]

Comment: I agree with @G.Anderson, and will add that some more context for this would be nice. Dummy data may be simpler, but it means we’re missing potentially crucial information.